# Add final two values of two running totals in Apple Numbers

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have two descending running totals, and I want to sum the last item in each running total.

I would like the total to be in a single cell, and the total in this instance to be `£2500 + £4492.55`. As the running total continues, I expect the total in this cell to update.

[image]

(Apple Numbers is similar to Excel, which is why I have used the Excel tag here).

Comment: Where do you want the result? And you want to sum 2600 + 2500 and 4592.55 + 4492.55?

Comment: I have updated my question to clear things up. Apologies.

Answer (score 2):

This approach works only if the calculation is not below the column of values, but above it:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(99^99,C:C,1))+INDEX(C:C,MATCH(99^99,C:C,1)-1)
```

[image]

**Edit**

Microsoft Support pages for [Index](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) and [Match](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a).  With the extraordinarily large number and the 1 as the last argument, Match will return the position of the last populated numeric cell. Index will then return the value of that cell. Repeat, but return the second last row, by subtracting a 1 from the Match result. Add the two results.

**Edit two**

Since you did not want to do what you first said you want to do, here is a formula for what you currently say you want to do. Assume the first list of numbers is in column C and the second list of numbers is in column G:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(99^99,C:C,1))+INDEX(C:C,MATCH(99^99,G:G,1))
```

**Edit three**

You've clarified in the comments that you're using Apple Numbers, not Microsoft Excel. Unfortunately the above formulae may not work in that system, and help for that probably is out of the scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can you explain what is happening here? I've never heard of the `INDEX` nor `MATCH` functions.

Comment: I've added some explanation.

Comment: I've added another formula that does what you currently describe.

Comment: I had to modify it slightly as it was getting the largest value from `C` in both sides of the formulae. `INDEX(C,MATCH(99^99,C,1)) + INDEX(G,MATCH(99^99,G,1)) `. However, this doesn't work, it returns `£7592.55`, which is the two largest values from both columns. It's VERY close though.

Comment: Your formula with `INDEX(C,MATCH...` cannot work because the `C` is not a valid reference. The column needs to be referenced as I showed in my formula. My formula will take the last value in the column. Your `Min()` formula will take the smallest value in the column which may or may NOT be the last value. Your answer marking is wrong.

Comment: I put `INDEX(C:C...` in and it autocorrected it to `INDEX(C...` after evaluating the formulae. Yes, mine is very simplistic, but yours just did not work for me. It references the £2800 in the first cell of the C column twice, and calculates £5600.

Comment: You can't be using Excel. What ARE you using?

Comment: Apple Numbers. It's in the title, but it has all the same functionality as Excel. Or at least that's what is claimed.

Comment: No, it is not the same. If you don't use Excel please don't tag with Excel. As this thread shows, Excel and Numbers are not the same and you wasted an hour of my time that I could have spent helping people who actually use Excel.

Comment: You also have Excel in the title. Why? If you don't use Excel? It's NOT the same.

Comment: I appreciate your time, but there is no tag for "Numbers". And despite what you may think you have actually helped me.

Comment: There is no tag for "Numbers" because it is off topic in this forum. Ask in SuperUser or in the "Ask Different" forum, which is for Apple products.

Answer (score 0):

I was overcomplicating things.

`MIN(C:C) + MIN(G:G)` yielded the result I was looking for.

Comment: But what if the last number is not the minimum? that would get you a wrong result

Comment: The formula I suggested below will take the last entry in columns C and G. That is what you specified in your question. You now post a "solution" that picks the minimum value, regardless of whether it's the last value or not. That may work for you right now, but it is not what you asked for in your question, i.e. "the last item in each running total".  You should unmark this answer, since it does not do what you asked for. Edit your question to require the "minimum value in each column", but I doubt that this will serve you in the long run, when calculations change the pattern.